# Enabling MP4 demuxer in FFmpeg configure command

Tags: ffmpeg, configure

I want to enable MP4 muxing and demuxing, H264 decoding and MJPEG encoding and disable everything else in FFmpeg configure command.

I know that I can use `--disable-everything` option and enable the needed components. When I list the demuxers and decoders using `--list-demuxers` and `--list-decoders` options, I do not see MP4 demuxer or decoder. I do see MP4 muxer in the muxers list.

What option should I use to enable MP4 demuxer in FFmpeg configure command?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The mov demuxer will demux the mp4. [Its the same demuxer] So you can enable that.

--enable-demuxer=mov

It will demux all of the following: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
[they are really all very very similar]. See libavformat/mov.c if you want to check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try what you have suggested.